# Verify the formula of bivariate Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

suppose that $X$ has a Poisson distribution with the rate $\lambda $ and suppose the conditional distribution of $Y$, given $X=x$, is binomial with parameters $x$ and $p$.

Problem: Let $Z=X-Y$ and $q=1-p$, verify $$p _{Y,Z}(y,z)=\frac{(p \lambda)^y}{y!} e^{-p \lambda} \frac{(q \lambda)^z)}{z!} e^{-q \lambda}$$ for non-negative integers $y$ and $z$.

> I know that \begin{align} p_{Y,Z}(y,z) & =P(Y=y,Z=z)  \\ &= P(Y=y,X=y+z)  \\& =P(Y=y \mid X=y+z) P(X=y+z) \end{align}

But I am still not sure how to tackle this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should begin by finding the (unconditional) distribution of $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  "[T]he conditional distribution of $\ Y\ $ given $\ X=x\ $ is binomial with parameters $\ x\ $ and $\ p\ $" means
$$
P(Y=y|X=y+z)={y+z\choose y}p^yq^z\ ,
$$
and "$\ X\ $ has a Poisson distribution with the rate $\ \lambda\ $" means
$$
P(X=y+z)=\frac{\lambda^{y+z}}{(y+z)!}e^{-\lambda}\ .
$$
If you substitute these expressions into your formula for $\ p_{Y,Z}(y,z)\ $, the rest should be fairly straightforward algebra.